# Is $\{x_{nk}\}$ defined by $x_{nk} = \frac{k}{k+n+1}$ computable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic, recursion, computability

Currently I am reading [Pour-El and Richard Computability in Analysis and Physics.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107168449)

In Chapater $0$, they give a definition of computable double sequence.

> Definition: A double sequence will be called computable if it is mapped onto a computable sequence by one of the standard recursive pairing functions from $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} $ onto $\mathbb{N}.$

However, I have trouble understanding the definition. 
My question is about verifying a certain example.

> Question: Let 
>   $$x_{nk} = \frac{k}{k+n+1}.$$
>   Is the double $\{x_{nk}\}$ above is computable?

Comment: That is an odd, but not incorrect, definition.  Usually we just say that a set of naturals $\mathbb S$ is computable if there is a program $P(x)$ such that $P(x) \iff x \in \mathbb S$, and if a set isn't of natural numbers then it is just up to you to decide the encoding based on your computing model.

Comment: Yes. I understand your meaning. But since I am reading their book, I might as well try to understanding their thinking, that is, why they consider such definition.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm telling you what you already know, but to answer this question affirmatively (it is true) you have to demonstrate the existence of a decision procedure that inputs $(a, b)$ (encoding as a single natural number) and outputs true iff $\exists nk ~.~ \frac{k}{k + n + 1} = \frac{a}{b}$  Edit: oh and that encoding is required by the definition to be one of the "standard" encodings in your book.

Comment: @DanielV Mind to elaborate your edited sentence in your previous comment? I kind of lost when you said encoding is required by the definition.

Comment: In traditional computational models (especially those in the lineage of Godel which you seem to be using), there's no such thing as an arbitrary datatype like a graph or a list or whatever.  *Every* program inputs a single natural number and outputs a single natural number.  So if you want to write a program that adds 2 natural numbers, you can't do it directly.  You have to imagine a bijection from the 2 inputs of the function to the 1 input of the program....

Comment: ...  Then, even though you are formally defining a program $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, you can pretend you are actually defining a program $\mathbb N^2 \to \mathbb N$.  Usually you are free to choose any encoding you like that isn't too crazy, like lexicographical ordering or whatever.  But your definition specifically says "one of the standard recursive pairing functions", so the book is saying "you gotta use one of the encodings that we've given you permission to use".  Your computing model is probably so strong that the choice doesn't really matter, any of the book ones will work.

Comment: @DanielV I think I understand your comments. But just want to confirm, it is not possible to give an example of computable double sequence using any one of the standard recursive pairing functions?

Comment: What in the world did I say that makes it sound like it isn't possible to give an example of a computable double sequence?  It is in fact much harder to give an example of a sequence that isn't computable.

Comment: @DanielV I apologize for the typo in my previous comment. It should be 'Is it possible...' rather than  'It is possible...'.

Comment: Are you trying to ask whether the choice of recursive pairing functions matters, or are you asking me for an example?

Comment: @DanielV I am asking for an example.

Comment: No, I don't have your book so I don't know the details.